# I really can't figure out where to start

Tags: c, algorithm, math

By using 9 numbers which are 1 to 9 you should find the number of ways to get N using multiplication and addition.

For example, if 100 is given, you would answer 7.

The reason is that there are 7 possible ways.

```
100 = 1*2*3*4+5+6+7*8+9

100 = 1*2*3+4+5+6+7+8*9

100 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8*9

100 = 12+3*4+5+6+7*8+9

100 = 1+2*3+4+5+67+8+9

100 = 1*2+34+5+6*7+8+9

100 = 12+34+5*6+7+8+9
```

If this question is given to you, how would you start?

Comment: Think about the problem systematically.  There are eight positions in between the nine digits.  Each can be occupied by '*', '+', or '' (concatenation).  You will need to loop over all three possibilities in all eight positions.  Then you will have to have some way of representing the sequence of operations and some way of evaluating it arithmetically.

Comment: This question would be better served on http://math.stackexchange.com/ because this question is not about programming.

Comment: There may be some clever mathematical trick that avoids having to do an exhaustive search here, but I don't know it.

Comment: Something to do with division and zero remainders..just a thought I got this may not be a solution..

Comment: @zwol  I am not so sure.  There are not eight positions because he has multi digit numbers in there.  Actually that's what makes it hard - I made an answer that assumed all single digit numbers and it was 11 lines of code but making every possible permutation of numbers including every length is a bit trickier.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `There are not eight positions` Did you read the part where zwol speaks about the concatenation operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we allowed to use parentheses?  That would expand the number of possibilities by a lot.

I would try to find the first additive term, let’s say 1×23, first.  There are a limited number of those, and since we can’t subtract, we know that if we get a term above our target, we can prune it from our search.  That leaves us looking for the solution to 23 + *f* = 100, where *f* is another formula of exactly the same form.  But that is exactly the same as solving the original problem for numbers 4–9 and target 77!  So call your algorithm recursively and add the solutions for that subproblem to the solutions to the original problem.  That is, if we have 23 + 4, are there any solutions to the subproblem with numbers 5–9 and *n* = 73?  Divide and conquer.

You might benefit from a dynamic table of partial solutions, since it's possible you might get the same subproblem in different ways: 1+2+3 = 1×2×3, so solving the subproblem with numbers 4–9 and target 94 twice duplicates work.

You are probably better going from right to left than from left to right, on the principle of most-constrained first.  89, 8×9, or 78+9 leave much less room for possible solutions than 1+2+3, 1×2×3, 12×3, 12+3 or 1×23.

Comment: Nope We are not allowed to use parentheses

Comment: This makes a whole lot of sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: @Lebanner Added a note about which direction to search from.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible operations

```
  addition
  multiplication
  combine, for example combine 1 and 2 to make 12
```

There are 8 positions for each operator. Hence, there are a total of 3^8 = 6561 possible equations. So I would start with

```
for ( i = 0; i < 6561; i++ )
```

Comment: I don't think the combine operation has eight positions.  12 and 21 are two different numbers.  So there are 72 different two digit numbers and if N is 1,000,000 then we may need 3, 4 and even 5 digit numbers and there are LOT of them.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah There's no indication in the question that you are allowed to change the order of the numbers. If you were able to reorder the numbers, there would be a lot more than 7 solutions, e.g. `1 + 2 * 3 + 4 + 65 + 7 + 8 + 9`

Comment: Fair enough. I must have misunderstood the question.